# A plugin changes my .htaccess file and I can't access httpd.conf as that's a shared server

Tags: htaccess, linux

In a CentOS with Bash A WordPress plugin (most likely WordFence) changes my `.htaccess` file by deleting extraneous (Apache PCRE) directives I've added there, and I can't access `httpd.conf` to add them there instead, as that's a **shared server** environment, so I'm quite stuck.

By "extraneous directives" I meant to all directives I've manually added below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

I didn't find a way to stop making WordFence do so.

### Considered workarounds:

1. Repeatedly (daily) re-creation of `.htaccess` from a local  template by a cronjob.
2. Repeatedly (daily) appending the extraneous parts of all .htaccess files from a template (via a complicated script).

Both solutions doesn't seem appealing.

### My question

What is the correct solution from your understanding?

Maybe creating the file from an online, formal, WordPress template? Maybe something else?

Comment: 1. Get rid of that plugin if it doesn't do what you want. 2. Remove write permission from the `.htaccess` file, so PHP can't change it.

Comment: Why using a plugin *(if it is the one mentioned by you)* which helps you to do some *(in this case it tries to help protecting your website)* but you don't want to ADD needed code to function as pretend. This plugin is NOT deleting already existing code in .htaccess at all when added that code correctly.