# How come there is no error if I upgrade WordPress core after locking .htaccess permissions to 644?

Tags: php, htaccess, upgrade, wp-cli, linux

How come there is no error if I upgrade WordPress core after locking `.htaccess`' permissions to 644?

I upgrade WordPress this way basically:

```
wp plugin update --all
wp core update
wp language core update
wp theme update --all
```

After locking .htaccess on 644 so that WordPress would be able to change it either from plugins or core upgrade, how come there is no error?

What is the mechanism that let's WordPress to pass over that file without any major error or crash? That lists it as an exception, generally, for upgrades?

Comment: what error are you waiting for ?

Comment: the question is not clear. why should there be an error?

Comment: I am asking why shouldn't be? I mean, this file is part of the eco system, and it doesn't get upgraded as well (or at least, isn't available for that).

Comment: As others also try to guess, like I do now also, is it useful to know what belongs  to a server and what to WP.  `.htaccess` is NOT part of WP and will not be upgraded/changed by WP itself without your permission *(through plugins/functions or by hand)* If web-server settings are allowing, it will be created as soon you command WP to create one by pressing the Save Changes in the Permalink section of the back-end. *(But all depends on the web-server settings if that file will be used or not at all, that is not up to WP nor plugins/functions)*

Comment: Duh, you are asking because of the [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/306276/15605) you made I assume. *(which I didn't read before commenting this question)*